# Msg "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'xxxx' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-appreview

I ran into this problem when I called */user_id/accounts* in the Facebook Graph API.

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '44902234665427' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": "AE1Wg3R8rZ07MqRWp3Jff1Q"
    }
}
```

According to [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/), I joined *pages_show_list* and *business_management* permissions, but there is still this mistake.

Here is code with JavaScript:

```
window.FB.api(`/${userId}/accounts?access_token=${accessToken}`, 'GET', (accountRes) => {

})
```

How can I solve it? And what causes it?

Comment: What do you mean by *"I joined* ***pages_show_list*** and ***business_management*** *permissions"*? It seem incomprehensible.

Comment: The search engines seem to like this question. It got about 700 views per day (on average until now).

Comment: Can you access just `/user_id/`, or does that throw the same error? If the latter - then the access token you are using, is probably for a different account.